# Converting old C code

Tags: c, gcc, porting

I have this code snippet in project source code which I work on

```
void func(void **p,size_t s)
{
    *p = malloc(s+sizeof(size_t));
    *(((size_t *)(*p))++) = s;
}
```

and gcc-4.7 does not compile it. gcc returns

```
lvalue required as increment operand
```

error message. I changed it into

```
stp = ((size_t *)(*p));
*(stp ++) = s;
```

and

```
stp = ((size_t *)(*p));
*stp = *stp + 1;
*stp = s;
```

gcc compiles both of them. But application does not work expected.
Is conversion true? And is there any tool for conversion?

Comment: I would take the programmer license from the guy produced the first code, if he had one.

Comment: @ Eugene Sh. , sorry. I update question.

Comment: Can you show, please, how this function called? I don't see a reason of the original error in this code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `struct app_info *dest; func((void **) &dest,sizeof(struct app_info));`

Comment: I wonder why the error states "*decrement*". :-S As only an "*increment[ation]*" is shown.

Comment: I saw such constructs like this back end of the 80s/beginning of the 90s. I think Turbo-C allows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea seems to be to allocate a certain amount of memory (`s`) **and** an additional amount to store this size allocated in the same area as a leading block and then return a pointer to just behind the stored size.

So try this:

```
void func(void ** p, size_t s)
{
  size_t * sp = malloc(s + sizeof s);
  if (NULL != sp)
  {
    *sp = s;
    ++sp;
  }

  *p = sp;
}
```

Btw, freeing the allocated memory, is not straight forward.

A typicall sequence of calls, also freeing what this function returns, would look like this then:

```
void * pv = NULL;
func(&pv, 42);
if (NULL != pv)
{
  /* Use 42 bytes of memory pointed to by pv here. */

  free(((char *) pv) - sizeof (size_t));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*(((size_t *)(*p))++) = s;

Breakdown:
*(
  (
    (size_t *) (*p)
  ) ++
) = s
```

Means : Take `*p` as a pointer to `size_t` (let's call that `ptr` for after), dereference it (= take the `size_t` typed value at the address `*p`), assign that value to s and finally increment `ptr` (which is to say increment the address in `*p` by the `sizeof(size_t)`.

You can translate that to:

```
size_t *ptr = (size_t*)(*p); //second pair of paren is optionnal
s = *ptr;
ptr = ptr + 1; //Warning: This will only modify the variable ptr and not
               //the data at its original place *p, if the remainder of
               //the program is based on that (which I highly suspect)
               //you should do instead :

(size_t*)*p = (size_t*)(*p) + 1; //This also ensures "+1" is treated as
                                 //"add the sizeof(size_t)" because *p
                                 //points to a size_t typed variable
```

You could also retype a variable and have it point at the same location as p and be done with the casts:

```
void func(void **p,size_t s)
{
  size_t **ptr = p;
  *ptr = malloc(s+sizeof(size_t));

  if (*ptr == NULL) etc...

  *((*ptr)++) = s;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the error is located where the OP thinks the error is located, maybe?

Comment: I do not understand this: "*`s = *ptr;`*"

Answer (score 0):

- `func2()` : Adding a variable can increase readability, IMHO. (and inlining will get rid of it, afterwards)
- The second function `func3()` demonstrates that using the return value instead of passing a (*opaque*) pointer by reference can avoid complexity and casts

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func2(void **p,size_t s)
{
    size_t **pp;
    pp = (size_t **) p; // only one cast
    *pp = malloc(s+sizeof(size_t));
    if (!*pp) return;
                          fprintf(stderr,"[mallocd %p]", *pp);
    *pp[0] = s;
    *pp += 1;
}

void *func3(size_t s)
{
    size_t *p;
    p = malloc(s+sizeof *p);
    if (!p) return NULL;
                          fprintf(stderr,"[mallocd %p]", p);
    p[0] = s;
    return p+1;
}

int main(void)
{
char *p = NULL , *p2 = NULL;

func2( (void**) &p, 666);       // yet another cast
fprintf(stderr,"returned p := %p\n", p);

p2 = func3( 666); // No cast!!!
fprintf(stderr,"returned p2 := %p\n", p2);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
void func(void **p,size_t s)
{
    *p = malloc(s+sizeof(size_t));
    *(*(size_t **)p)++ = s;
}
```

This is allocating `s` bytes of memory, plus enough extra to hold `s`, storing `s` at the start of that space and modifying `*p` to point just after that.

More sensible and clearer (and avoiding casts!) would be:

```
void *func(size_t s)
{
    size_t *p = malloc(s + sizeof(size_t));
    if (p) *p++ = s;
    return p;
}
```

but that requires changing the code that calls this function to take the return value and store it wherever desired, rather than passing an extra pointer as an argument:

```
some_ptr = func(needed_size);
```

rather than

```
func((void **)&some_ptr, needed_size);
```

also avoiding casts...